# compiler error inside a template-discarded code

Tags: c++, templates

Following code compiles fine:

```
template <bool X>
struct A;

template <>
struct A<true> {
  int x = 1;
};

template <>
struct A<false> {
};

template <bool X>
void f()
{
  A<X> a;
  if constexpr (X) {
    if (a.x == 1)
      ;
  }
}

int main()
{
  f<false>();
}
```

Inside the function `f()` the code for `X==true` is indeed valid because `a.x` exists in this case. In any case, `f()` is instantiated for `X==false` only.

A slightly different code, however does not compile:

```
template <bool X>
struct A;

template <>
struct A<true> {
  int x = 1;
};

template <>
struct A<false> {
};

void f()
{
  static constexpr bool X = false;
  A<X> a;
  if constexpr (X) {
    if (a.x == 1)
      ;
  }
}

int main()
{
  f();
}
```

The error is:

```
test.cpp:18:11: error: ‘struct A<false>’ has no member named ‘x’
   18 |     if (a.x == 1)
```

I fail to see the concrete difference in calling `f<false>()` with the first code, and `f()` with the second code.

Why does the compiler refuse the second code?

Comment: the false branch in `constexpr if` is only discarded inside templates. When `f` is not a template then all branches of the `constexpr if` must be valid. I'd expect that there are dupilcates...

Comment: not sure what is the right standardese wording, cppref says ["Outside a template, a discarded statement is fully checked. if constexpr is not a substitute for the #if preprocessing directive: "](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if), ie it is discarded, but it is *checked* when not insided a template